# Modify Display of JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify the display of data returned as JSON based on the value of one of the fields in the first returned object.

Here's an example of the array of objects returned in the success callback:

**JSON Data ViewPricing = N**

```
[{
  "ItemCount": 2,
  "ViewPricing": "N"
}, {
  "ProductID": "4600033",
  "ProdMfg": "",
  "Desc": "Cambridge&#32;IR&#32;Driftwood",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "ExtPrice": " ",
  "UnitPrice": " "
}, {
  "ProductID": "4600068",
  "ProdMfg": "",
  "Desc": "Cambridge&#32;IR&#32;Charcoal&#32;Grey",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "ExtPrice": " ",
  "UnitPrice": " "
}, {
  "ItemTotExtPrice": ""
}]
```

**JSON Data ViewPricing = Y**

```
[{
  "ItemCount": 1,
  "ViewPricing": "Y"
}, {
  "ProductID": "60PRO50BL",
  "ProdMfg": "",
  "Desc": "Duraflo&#32;Weatherpro&#32;50&#32;Vent&#32;Black",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "ExtPrice": "$10.95",
  "UnitPrice": "$10.95"
}, {
  "ItemTotExtPrice": "$10.95"
}]
```

**jQuery**

```
   function getPallet() {
    "use strict";
    var palletContent = $('#palletContent'),
        palletBtns = $('#palletBtns'),
        spinner = '<div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="spinner-wave"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div><span class="text-center"><b>Loading Pallet...</b></span></div>';
    palletBtns.addClass('hide');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: Config.engineUrl + '?aShoppingCart',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            palletContent.empty().append(spinner);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            palletContent.empty();
            if (data[0].ItemCount === 0) {
                palletContent.html('<div class="alert alert-danger ma10"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="pl10">You have no items in your pallet.</b></center></div>');
            } else {
                var items = [],
                    subtotal = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    if (item.ViewPricing === "Y") {
                        console.log('View Pricing: True');
                        if (i > 0 && i < data.length - 1) {
                            items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td><td class="text-right">' + item.UnitPrice + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                    } else if (item.ViewPricing === "N") {
                        console.log('View Pricing: False');
                        if (i > 0 && i < data.length - 1) {
                            items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                    if (i === data.length - 1) {
                        subtotal.push(item.ItemTotExtPrice);
                    }
                });
                palletContent.append('<table id="miniPallet" class="table mb0"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Item </th><th class="text-center">Qty</th><th class="text-right">Price</th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr><td class="text-left"><strong>Subtotal</strong></td><td></td><td class="text-right"><strong>' + subtotal + '</strong.</td></tr></tfoot><tbody>' + items.join('') + '</tbody></table>');
                palletBtns.removeClass('hide');
            }
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
}
```

**What I'm Trying to Do**

What I want to do is alter the items data conditionally based on the value of the "View Pricing" field.

*If (item.ViewPricing === "Y") , I want the pushed html/data to be:*

```
 items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td><td class="text-right">' + item.UnitPrice + '</td></tr>');
```

*If (item.ViewPricing === "Y") , I want the palletContent html/data to be:*

```
 palletContent.append('<table id="miniPallet" class="table mb0"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Item </th><th class="text-center">Qty</th><th class="text-right">Price</th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr><td class="text-left"><strong>Subtotal</strong></td><td></td><td class="text-right"><strong>' + subtotal + '</strong.</td></tr></tfoot><tbody>' + items.join('') + '</tbody></table>');
```

*If (item.ViewPricing === "N") , I want the pushed data to be:*

```
 items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td></tr>');
```

*If (item.ViewPricing === "N") , I want the palletContent html/data to be:*

```
 palletContent.append('<table id="miniPallet" class="table mb0"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Item </th><th class="text-center">Qty</th></tr></thead><tbody>' + items.join('') + '</tbody></table>');
```

**Updated - Working Code**

```
 function getPallet() {
        "use strict";
        var palletContent = $('#palletContent'),
            palletBtns = $('#palletBtns'),
            spinner = '<div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="spinner-wave"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div><span class="text-center"><b>Loading Pallet...</b></span></div>';
        palletBtns.addClass('hide');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: Config.engineUrl + '?aShoppingCart',
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                palletContent.empty().append(spinner);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                palletContent.empty();
                if (data[0].ItemCount === 0) {
                    palletContent.html('<div class="alert alert-danger ma10"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="pl10">You have no items in your pallet.</b></center></div>');
                } else {
                var items = [],
                    subtotal = [];
                if (data[0].ViewPricing === "Y") {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        if (i > 0 && i < data.length - 1) {
                            items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td><td class="text-right">' + item.UnitPrice + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                        if (i === data.length - 1) {
                            subtotal.push(item.ItemTotExtPrice);
                        }
                    });
                    palletContent.append('<table id="miniPallet" class="table mb0"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Item </th><th class="text-center">Qty</th><th class="text-right">Price</th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr><td class="text-left"><strong>Subtotal</strong></td><td></td><td class="text-right"><strong>' + subtotal + '</strong.</td></tr></tfoot><tbody>' + items.join('') + '</tbody></table>');
                } else if (data[0].ViewPricing === "N") {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        if (i > 0 && i < data.length - 1) {
                            items.push('<tr><td class="text-left"><span class="itemNum">' + item.ProductID + '</span></br><span class="desc">' + item.Desc + '</span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="qty">' + item.Quantity + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                        if (i === data.length - 1) {
                            subtotal.push(item.ItemTotExtPrice);
                        }
                    });
                    palletContent.append('<table id="miniPallet" class="table mb0"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Item </th><th class="text-center">Qty</th></tr></thead><tbody>' + items.join('') + '</tbody></table>');
                }
                palletBtns.removeClass('hide');
}
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem or error ?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to do another `if (...) {...} else {...}`...? What exactly do you want to know? I'm not seeing the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: I modified the jQuery code above. There is a few issues: (1) Inside the each function, I modified the if statement. The issue here is that the pushed items always return the html in the item.ViewPricing = "Y" condition even though it appears were entering the item.ViewPricing = "N" condition. (2) I don't know how to then change the html that gets appended on the "palletContent.append()" line based on this condition.

Comment: your code should work as is. Are you sure your data contains what you think it contains?

Comment: @Kevin I think so. I added the response data for each condition above.

Comment: uhm.. you have an array with three objects, and only the first in both cases has that key... *confused*

Comment: Look at the JSON data. The first element contains the count and the pricing info, only the second up to and excluding the last contain the actual items, and the last contains the total. Yet your code is treating it as array of items.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin & Chris. My inexperience got the best of me here. I have this working the way I want it to now. I added my updated code above. The main issue, as you said, was that I was looping through the entire array in my each function when I only wanted to loop through the "inner" objects.

Comment: Your "JSON data" is not JSON, they are JavaScript arrays.